# How to design to avoid DataBase access on main thread exception while getting my fields initialized?

Tags: java, android, database, multithreading

I have some fields that need to get initialized by accessing to database (or network) when activity or fragment get created, so a natural way of doing this is to use TaskQueue to let db access happen in worker thread inside onCreate(). However, I need to use them in onStart(), but since db access is asynchronous, the fields may not get initialized when onStart() gets called. I'm wondering what is the best way to solve this kind of dilemma.

Access DB directly in onCreate -> DB access on main thread exception
Async access DB in onCreate -> onStart() doesn't get the initialized fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start the second thread in onCreate, and put up a loading UI until you have the result.  When you get the callback you put up the real UI.  There is no way around it, you can't use that data until the server has sent it to you